# If $x \le \beta \quad\forall \beta > \alpha$, then $x \le \alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> If $x \le \beta \quad\forall \beta > \alpha$, then $x \le \alpha$. ($x, \alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive real numbers)

It seems simple but I don't know how to prove it. I tried considering a $\beta'>\alpha$ such that $x\le\beta'$ but $x>\alpha$, but it doesn't showing me any contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1>\alpha$ and take $\beta=\frac{x_1+\alpha}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x>\alpha$ then $x>\frac{x+\alpha}{2}>\alpha$. Now take $\beta=\frac{x+\alpha}{2}$ to get the desired contradiction.